# Loading leaflet.markercluster in a js file in a node project

Tags: javascript, node.js, leaflet, leaflet.markercluster

I'm trying to use the library in a project importing the markercluster (line: import './libs/leaflet.markercluster-src';) in a node. project on a js file, but when I build the project it does not create the mapping source of markercluster and if I copy the leaflet.markercluster file in dist/libs and run the project the result is the next error:

Plugin component error Error: (SystemJS) L is not defined
ReferenceError: L is not defined

I'm using the next versions:
Leaftlet 0.7
eaflet.markercluster 0.7

Can you help me to resolve this issue?

Comment: There is no version 0.7 for Leaflet.markercluster (https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.markercluster/releases)

Comment: And how are you building this? Webpack? rollup? browserify? How does your bundler configuration look like? How does your project file structure look like? There's too little info to know what's going wrong.

Comment: I'm using the markercluster version (https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.markercluster/tree/leaflet-0.7) for leaflet 0.7,

Comment: I'm using the markercluster version (https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.markercluster/tree/leaflet-0.7), I'm creating a plugin to grafana and need to load a map with marker clustering